# How to make "Site Page" link field in Wygwam show URL?

Tags: wygwam, pages

When I create a link in Wygwam, a box appears that lets me choose "Site Page" and select an entry from the Pages module.

My problem is that I have several pages with the same name, because each page is accessible to a specific member group, so sometimes the list of options looks like this:

```
About
Services
Contact
Contact
Contact
Contact
Work
etc.
```

Is there a way to make that Site Page list show more detail, like the full URL, or the nested layout that you see when viewing pages in the Pages module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess the answer is no without a hack to the addon or building a custom extension.

If you want to go the extension route, here's a very good code starting point:
https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_template_links